# I get "this.props.comments.map is not a function" or other errors if I click on a photo after deleting a different one in my MERN app

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

When I remove a photo from my app I can't click on any of the others without refreshing the page.
The app is a website written in the MERN stack with Redux. It is a simple stream of photos you can click on and see the photo in its own page with comments.

The problem is after I delete a photo from the stream I cannot click on any other photos without getting the 'Cannot read property of undefined' error.
If I refresh the page I am able to click on any photos again.
You can visit the site [here](https://peaceful-retreat-20560.herokuapp.com/), upload a photo, delete a photo, then click on a different photo to see the blank screen and error in the console.

When I run the app locally I get slightly different errors, but the problem seems to be empty arrays. Sometimes the error says 'this.props.comments.map is not a function' and sometimes it is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of null' so, for some reason the DOM thinks(?) the photos and comments are empty arrays?
Between the React components, Redux actions and reducers and the NodeJS server I hope I can provide enough info.

[image]

Since the error is showing the comment 'action' I will start by displaying that function.

```
export const individualComments = filename => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/comments/comments/${filename}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: INDIV_COMMENTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
  .catch(err =>
    dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
  );
}
```

We are still in Redux with this next block of code. Here is the reducer for this action. The case INDIV_COMMENTS

```
export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case INDIV_COMMENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        comments: action.payload
      }

      default:
      return state;    
  }
}
```

Next we will move out of Redux, out of the client.
Here is that route the action calls from the server side in `/api`.

```
router.get('/comments/:filename', (req, res) => {
  Comment.find({page: req.params.filename
    }, (err, files) => {
      // Check if files
      if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        return res.json(files);
      } else if (files) {
        return res.json(files);
      }  else {
        return res.json(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Here is a part of the React component in one of the errors.

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.submitFormHandler = this.submitFormHandler.bind(this)

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.singleView(this.props.match.params.filename);
    this.props.individualComments(this.props.match.params.filename);
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  submitFormHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const ncomment = (this.refs.aComment.value)
    const page = this.props.match.params.filename
    this.props.commentUploader(ncomment, page)
    this.refs.aComment.value = '';
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.props.comments && !this.props.photos ) {
      return (
    <div className="center">Loading...</div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
```

...  Skipping some React code here for brevity

```
            <h4 className="another-comment">Comments</h4>
            {this.props.comments.map(post => (
            <div className="post-card" key={post._id}>
                <div className="card-content">
                    <span className="card-title  red-text">Date:{post.date}</span>
                  <p className="comment-text-in">Comment: {post.content}</p>
                </div>
              </div>))}
```

...  Skipping some more React code here for brevity

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    array: state.photos.array,
    comments: state.comments.comments
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  { allPhotos, singleView, commentUploader,
    individualComments })(Post);
```

Thank you for your help. I hope I have provided enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by looking at the state with the Redux Devtools browser extension.
The problem was with the filename associated with the comments upon deletion of the file's comments.
I had the action set to `comments: action.payload` when it should have been `comments: null`.
The comment action was asking the db for the comments for a deleted photo. This was only happening behind the scenes because the filename in the browser was asking for the correct, (clicked) photo.

```
  export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

      case INDIV_COMMENTS:
        return {
          ...state,
          comments: action.payload
        }
        default:
        return state;    
    }
  }
```

Changed to

```
  export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

      case INDIV_COMMENTS:
        return {
          ...state,
          comments: null
        }

        default:
        return state;    
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Anytime you see 'Cannot read property of undefined', or 'Cannot read property of null', you should determine why the object you are looking at is unexpectedly undefined/null. For instance, in the case of `Cannot read property 'filename' of null'`, you should look at all of the lines that access the `filename` property, and determine why the thing you are accessing is null. In this case, the question is what would cause `this.props.match.params` to be null.
2. Anytime you see `this.props.comments.map`, you know that `comments` is not an array (empty or otherwise). Maybe it's an object or a String, but it probably isn't null or undefined (since you would have gotten some other error). So look at the parent component and determine why it would pass a non-null, non-undefined, non-array value as the `comments` prop.
3. One part that does stick out to my is your API endpoint. Right now, if files is null, 0, undefined, an empty string, or false, it will be rendered as that JSON value (which is probably not what you want). If it is falsey, you should probably return an error code (probably a 404), since that presumably implies that the resource doesn't actually exist.

Unfortunately, there isn't quite enough context to point to the actual bug, and it may well be a combination of things. I would recommend either adding console logs or using the browser debugger to inspect both the response you are getting back from the server, and those values that are causing bad accesses before they are used. You'll need to work backwards from there to determine why the values are not what you expect.

Comment: I will spend some time pondering these things for my issue. I'm sure the problem centers around the removing of an element from the array of elements, which is also an href, (a link to it's own post), and the app getting confused about which element I am clicking on after one was removed. So, the delete function in the 'action' and / or 'reducer' need some special attention. (I think. I'm not sure exactly.)